# Connecting Kali to the Internet

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have installed Kali on my raspberry pi. I've managed to connect to it through ssh using Putty, but I cannot access the Internet.
To be more specific, I can neither update/upgrade nor can I `ping www.google.com` but I can however `ping 8.8.8.8`.
The PI and my desktop are connected to the same router.
I have checked the routes, the gateway, the interface, I have changed the cable thinking that it might be the physical link but nothing works. Any suggestions ?

```
root@kali:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a02:2f09:33ba:d200:ba27:ebff:fe54:38fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe54:38fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdf8:b85b:7d29:0:ba27:ebff:fe54:38fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:54:38:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 561  bytes 39987 (39.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 294  bytes 42374 (41.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@kali:~# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com(bud02s24-in-x04.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400d:803::2004)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6007ms

root@kali:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=13.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=11.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=12.6 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.844/12.764/14.216/0.880 ms
```

P.S. I have connected the same device with the same OS to a different router at a friend of mine and it worked without any adjustments.

Comment: Some more details would be great. Any logs?

Comment: If you can ping 8.8.8.8 then the problem is **obviously not** with the routing, but with the DNS.  Try setting your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and it should probably be fine unless your firewall blocks it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I've tried that already, for some odd reason, before i edit anything in `/etc/resolv.conf` there are 2 namespaces, 1 which is my gateway and another one which is the gateway of my second router ( I have cascading routers). Changing resolv.conf doesn't work either

Comment: What does `dig a google.com @8.8.8.8` give you?

Comment: `-bash: dig: command not found

Comment: @JuliePelletier I have set the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 again, and then called `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`. This resets the `resolv.conf` to the previous values.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Can't you change it in the network manager?

Comment: I have disabled the DNS overwriting by the DHCP ( added `dns=none` in `[main]` section), but it still doesn't work. After restarting the networking service it still gets reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a lack of IPv6 connectivity.

As your Pi is getting an IPv6 address assigned to it, the system will prefer to use IPv6. However, for whatever reason, you can not get an outbound internet connection.

Ideally, you would check your router and other computers, and make sure IPv6 is working on them. But, in the meantime, you can just disable it.

To do this, add the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Upon your system coming back online, IPv6 will be disabled and you should be able to establish a normal connection to any IPv4 website.

Comment: Unbelievable ... Thank you very much. It works like a charm now!

Comment: No worries. This is definitely a hacky solution, and the ideal thing would be to look at *why* IPv6 isn't working, but it'll at least get you online in the meantime.